# Firebase Storage security rules - read condition not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

Regardless what I put in the read condition, I able to read the files

For example:

```
service firebase.storage {
    match <firebase-storage-url> {
        match /{userId}/{allPaths=**}{
            allow read: if '1'==   '2';
            allow write: if true
        }
    }
}
```

Although 1 not equal 2 I able to read firebase storage files. How it can happens?

Comment: Are you using download tokens or downloading through the SDK?

Comment: You can explain what you mean?

Comment: I take the file url and download it through http url connection

Comment: And not through firebase download method

Comment: That method bypasses security rules, since you're using a public but unguessable URL. Rules only apply to requests that come directly from the SDK, not from an arbitrary download URL.

Comment: You right! It's works! Thanks